# Static Dictionary<T,T> sharing information accross sessions. How to stop this?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

In my web project, I am using Static List. So say suppose I have 2 users (A, B) logged in to my website at the same time, then this List will store some information about A and as well as B. But say when I process B List's records, A's List's are getting processed instead of B's.

Can somebody point out the problem please?, also please suggest me some possible solution to avoid this problem.

I am using ASP.NET C# 3.5.

Thank you in advance :)

**Edit:**

Now I have changed the data type from Dictionary to List, but still the same problem...

Comment: What's your reason for having a static dictionary?  Seems like user specific data needs to go in their profile, not in a static variable.

Comment: Eric I am using static dictionary because I have to retain the data in dictionary as my requirement makes me refresh the same page many times.

Comment: **Exactly** what data you want to save? While many are suggesting you to used the `Session` object, at lest 50% of the times it's an anti-pattern that in the long run causes more problems that it solves.

Comment: @Arry, you seem to be missing something in the answers. Nobody is telling you *not* to use a dictionary. They're telling you *not* to make it static. The issue is not your choice of container, it's your choice of how you keep it alive.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: I do acknowledge this thing, but in my case I have to retain the value in Dictionary/List, and without making it static how can I do that? Can you give some example?

Comment: @Arry you need have to use session and store your dictionary in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `static` variable is one that is the *same* for all instances of a particular class.  So this means your website uses the *exact same* dictionary for User A, B, C, D, etc.  Essentially whichever user last writes to the dictionary is the one whose content you will see, regardless of which user is looking.

As other's have suggested, you can use `Session` variables.  These are stored in the server's memory, and are related to a specific browser 'session' (i.e. user).

Personally, I prefer to use the `ViewState` as this is stored in the response to the browser, and returned to you whenever the page makes a postback.  This means less memory usage on the server, the viewstate is not volatile across sessions (or subject to application resets like session).  However this also means that whatever you are storing is sent across the wire, so you would never want to store things like credit card numbers, SSN's, etc.

It also means that if you're storing a lot of very large objects, you're going to have a very large response and postback (possibly slowing the cycle), so you have to be more careful about how and what you store.

So that's a few different options for you, you should do the research and decide which is best for your requirements.

Comment: You recommend ViewState. If I hit F5 to refresh the page, is the ViewState going to go back to the server? If I navigate to a different page, does my ViewState go with me? ViewState is not useful for scenarios that do not involve direct postbacks.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram And when your user press CTRL-N on IE, how will Session react to having two tabs that point to the same Session? You can only choose the method of hanging yourself, but the hanging will happen :-) And you can use `Server.Transfer` to move data between pages. It isn't easy to do it, but it's doable.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram He never specified the context of his problem, so I was offering options for him to investigate.  As I said, there are drawbacks to either solution.

Comment: @xanatos, Coding Gorilla, I agree, there are tradeoffs and pitfalls. It's helpful to state what those are. Judging by some of the feedback from the OP, it would be *extremely* helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Storing values in session is like:

```
Session["mykey"] = value;
```

And reading values from session is like:

```
Object value = Session["mykey"];
```

The session will time out after a couple of minutes and the value would then be null.
To avoid this consider using:

```
Viewstate["mykey"] = value;
```

Viewstate is used exactly like session except that the value has to be serializable.
The viewstate is send to the client and back again so consider the amount of data that you want to store this way.  The viewstate is stored in "__VIEWSTATE" and encoded in base64.

Comment: +1 but... Please don't tell anyone that `Viewstate is used exactly like Session`. Don't corrupt the minds of young progammers with false informations.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a static dictionary. Use Session variables to store information about a user's session.

For better information, you will have to provide us with a bit more information: what records? in what format? etc.

Comment: I need to store information in the form of Key Value pair, so how can I achieve this without using Dictionary?

Comment: As some have stated, store a dictionary in a session variable. One dictionary per session - no dictionary will be over-written with another session's/user's data.

Comment: Ok I can store dictionary in session but I have to process the data present in Dictionary.. so I will I process the data of Dictionary then?

Comment: @Casperah has an excellent example ...no need for me to duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

When a variable is declared `static`, that means there is exactly 1 instance of that variable per class (this also includes classes in web applications).

Thus, a static variable is not tied to a user. If you need to store data specific to a user, consider using a [Session variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

Comment: I need to store information in the form of Key Value pair, how can I achieve this using session variable?

Comment: You can store your key value data structure (i.e. Dictionary<T,T>) in a Session variable (it accepts type `object`), you'll just need to typecast it back when you want to read it.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the dictionary in the Session, that way each user would have their own and the code wouldn't have access to others.

Or if you sometimes want to be able to access other users' info, you could declare it as

```
static Dictionary<String, Dictionary<T, T>>
```

where the string key is the unique user id.

Comment: wouldn't this be dangerous? possibly sharing info from one dictionary with the wrong user?